# xpath and xml namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath

How i can access to my url strings in my xml using xpath ?

```
                <images xmlns:a="http://.../Arrays">
                   <a:string>http://images...233/Detail.jpg</a:string>
                   <a:string>http://images....233/Detail2.jpg</a:string>
               </images>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
/images/*[local-name()='string']   This will get you the nodes.


/images/*[local-name()='string']/text()   This will give the text content in the node.
```